# Query a table only to see the rows that match rows in two other tables

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, inner-join

I have two folders, that have files in them. The files and their data are stored in tables, one table per folder. The folder tables only have data of the files that are currently in the folders. I have another Table that has all the data inside it even files that are no longer in the two folders, just to keep track of history.

I require a query that will show the contents of both tables, but not files that are no longer in the folders.

For more information:

- Each file has a ID
- Each ID is Different
- Folder A does not have any matching IDs as Foler B
- This data is stored in Access 2010

What I thought would work:

I was thinking of an `inner join` using the third table and the other two folder tables, with a `where` clause that only shows:

```
TableC.ID = TableA.ID AND TableC.ID = TableB.ID
```

But this did not function.

Answer (score 0):

```
select commonColumns, AOnlyColumn, NULL As BOnlyColumn
from FolderA

UNION

select commonColumns, NULL, BOnlyColumn
from FolderB
```

Comment: Hi, The union does work for any matching columns, but what if there are some coumns in Folder B that aren't in Folder A?

Comment: Then you use a placeholder column. I'll update my answer to show how it would look

Comment: That makes sence, yes that does work.
I realize now that, i need to query the data in Table C but only show the Table C ID that = Table B ID o Table A ID, since table C has all the ID's and Past ID's it also contains changed data to the columns unlike the Folder A Table and B Table they are only imports of the current data of the libraries, but we add additional data to those ID's in Table C... I hope there is a way to make it funcion Where i can select * from Table C where ID.Table C = ID.TableB or Table A like both in b and a. THANK YOU!

Comment: Is there any way to make this work without the union clause? because the Data in the Folder Table A and Table B is only the imports of the data in those folders, But Table C has all the data archived and aditional information.

Comment: You will need the union, but you could change the existing queries that make up the union so that each one also joins to TableC.

Answer (score 0):

Try....

```
select ID,detail1,details From TableA 
union
Select ID,detail1,detail2... from TableB
```